# ¿Como poner el mismo menu en la izquierda y derecha?

Tags: css, html5

Buenas, Estoy intentando agregar un menú en la izquierda y derecha pero solo he podido agregarlo a la izquierda(mía) pero  quiero agregar otro idéntico menú pero ala derecha alguien tiene alguna idea de que tengo mal en mi código ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="wide wow-animation" lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Site Title-->
  <title>Fresh Farms</title>
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <!-- Stylesheets-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Berkshire+Swash%7COpen+Sans:300,500,400,400italic,700,600,600italic%7CRaleway%7CLato:400,700%7CRoboto:400">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--[if lt IE 10]>
    <div style="background: #212121; padding: 10px 0; box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3); clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative; z-index:1;"><a href="https://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/"><img src="images/ie8-panel/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today."></a></div>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  <!-- <script src="/cdn-cgi/apps/head/3ts2ksMwXvKRuG480KNifJ2_JNM.js"></script> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <style>
    
   
    *{
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

    }

nav {
  background-color:transparent;
  background-position:center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%; 
  margin:10px;
  display: block;
  
}

  nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

    nav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      list-style-type: none;
      
      -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
        -o-transition: all 0.2s;
        transition: all 0.2s; 
    }
      
      nav > ul > li > a > .caret {
        border-right: 4px solid transparent;
        border-left: 4px solid transparent;
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
  
        -webkit-transition: color 0.1s linear;
          -moz-transition: color 0.1s linear;
        -o-transition: color 0.1s linear;
          transition: color 0.1s linear; 
      }

      nav > ul > li > a {
        color: #aaa;
        display: block;
        line-height: 56px;
        padding: 0 24px;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

        nav > ul > li:hover {
          background-color:transparent;
        }

        nav > ul > li:hover > a {
          color: green;
        }

        nav > ul > li:hover > a > .caret {
          background-color:white;
        }
      
      nav > ul > li > div {
        background-color:white;
        border-top: 0;
        border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
        display: none;
        margin: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 165px;
        visibility: hidden;
  
        -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
        -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
        -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
        -transition: opacity 0.2s;
      }

        nav > ul > li:hover > div {
          display: block;
          opacity: 1;
          visibility: visible;
        }

          nav > ul > li > div ul > li {
            display: block;
          }

            nav > ul > li > div ul > li > a {
              color: #fff;
              display: block;
              padding: 12px 24px;
              text-decoration: none;
            }

              nav > ul > li > div ul > li:hover > a {
                background-color:white;
              }
/*
nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;


}

nav a {
font-size: 14px;
  outline: none;
}*/
/*
video{
  min-width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
}*/

/*Nuevo codigo*/
video + h1 {
  z-index:100;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  font-size:100px;
}
/*Nuevo codigo*/

.titulo{

  margin-left:100px; 
}
.derecha{
  margin-right:100px;
}
.logo_principal{

width:140px;
height:130PX;
left:600px;
}

  </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <!-- Page-->
  <div class="page text-center text-md-left">

<video id="video" autoplay loop>
        <source src="video/1_1.mp4" type=video/mp4 >
    </video>

 <h1 style="color:white;">Titulo en el video</h1>
    <header>
    <!--
          <nav>
       <br> <br><br><br>
   
       <li class="titulo" style="display:inline-block;float:left; padding:10px; font-weight:bold;"><a style="color:white; background:#92E32F; padding:9px; border-radius:10%;"   href="#">HOME</a></li>
       <li class="titulo" style="display:inline-block;float:left; padding:10px; font-weight:bold;"><a style="color:white;"  href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
       </li>

       <li class="titulo" style="display:inline-block;float:left; padding:10px; font-weight:bold;"><a style="color:white;" href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
       <li class="derecha" style="display:inline-block; float:right; padding:10px; font-weight:bold;"><a style="color:white;"  href="#">RESPONSIBLE FARMING</a></li>
       <li class="derecha" style="display:inline-block; float:right; padding:10px; font-weight:bold;"><a  style="color:white;" href="#">GET IN TOUCH</a></li>
        <li class="derecha" style="display:inline-block; float:right; padding:10px; font-weight:bold;"><a  style="color:white;" href="#"></a></li>

        
        

    
        <center>
            <img class="logo_principal" style="position: absolute;bottom:-30px;" src="images/FreshFarms.png" width="150" alt="Logo Fresh Farms">
 </center>
          <br>
 
     </nav>-->

     <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a style="color:black;" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
      <a style="color:black;" href="#">Products <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <div>
                <ul>

                    <li><a  style="color:black;" href="#">Chair</a></li>
                    <li><a  style="color:black;" href="#">Table</a></li>
                    <li><a  style="color:black;" href="#">Cooker</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a style="color:black;" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a style="color:black;" href="#">Help</a></li>
    </ul>

        <center><br>
            <img class="logo_principal" style="position: absolute;bottom:-30px;" src="images/FreshFarms.png" width="150" alt="Logo Fresh Farms">
 </center>
 
</nav>
  </header>
```

Comment: Cambia el color de la letra a negro (la tienes en blanco) para que la gente pueda ver lo que tienes en el snipet, también tienes otros elementos con fondo blanco. No se ve nada.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con menú a la derecha o a la izquierda?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar los siguiente
Haciendo resaltar "Left" y "Right" y "Position: Absolute;"

```css
.menu {
   display: inline-flex;
   list-style:none;
   padding: 0px;
   

  }

  .izq {
   position: absolute;
   top: 15px;
   left: 15px;
  }

  .der {
   position: absolute;
   top: 15px;
   right: 15px;
  }

  .menu a {
   padding: 5px;
   color: orange;
   text-decoration:none;
  }

  .menu a:hover {
   padding: 5px;
   color: pink;
  }
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="izq">
  <ul class="menu">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Acerca</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Soporte</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="der">
  <ul class="menu">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Acerca</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Soporte</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>

</body>
```